# Magento Newsletter Sends too slow

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

hope someone can help me here

**I have 30,000 email subscribers on our new Magento 1.9.1 CE store**

It is taking a week to send out all the emails :(    Can I speed up the send out by allowing more emails per Cron send?..  I have searched this on Google & found nothing specific..

What is doubly strange is an earlier Magento CE install 1.7 used to send out newsletters a lot faster..  since the 1.91 upgrade it seems to have gone very slow..

Aside from suggesting to me another newsletter sending service provider like MailChimp?   I do like using the generic News sender in Magento.. I have seen Mailchimps statistics &they are great but not needed..

any ideas?  I am free to any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's hardcoded to 20 emails in this file.

> magento/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php

```
public function scheduledSend($schedule)
{
    $countOfQueue  = 3;
    $countOfSubscritions = 20;

    $collection = Mage::getModel('newsletter/queue')->getCollection()
        ->setPageSize($countOfQueue)
        ->setCurPage(1)
        ->addOnlyForSendingFilter()
        ->load();

     $collection->walk('sendPerSubscriber', array($countOfSubscritions));
}
```

Of course the proper way to fix this would be to rewrite using a Magento module, but that requires programming experience.